# findQuery() is not working in ember-data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Fixture contain list of contacts and each contact has contact type.
I am trying to filtrate contact records using .findQuery() but it is throwing following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {.....} has no method 'findQuery'
```

I have listed my code here :

```
Grid.Store = DS.Store.extend({
                  revision: 12,
                  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
            }); 

    Grid.ModalModel =  DS.Model.extend({
    fname: DS.attr('string'),
    lname: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    contactno: DS.attr('string'),
    gendertype: DS.attr('boolean'),
    contactype: DS.attr('number')
});

Grid.ModalModel.FIXTURES = [
                       {
                         id: 1,
                         fname: "sachin",
                         lname: "gh",
                         email: "gh",
                         contactno: "4542154",
                         gendertype: true,
                         contactype: 1
                       },
                       {
                         id: 2,
                         fname: "amit",
                         lname: "gh",
                         email: "gh",
                         contactno: "4542154",
                         gendertype: true,
                         contactype: 2
                       },
                       {
                         id: 3,
                         fname: "namit",
                         lname: "gh",
                         email: "gh",
                         contactno: "4542154",
                         gendertype: true,
                         contactype: 1
                       }
                      ];
```

Controller Code:

```
        totpersonalcontact:function(){ 
        return Grid.ModalModel.findQuery({ contactype: 2 }).get('length'); 
    }.property('@each.isLoaded'),
    totfriendcontact:function(){ 
        return Grid.ModalModel.findQuery({ contactype: 3 }).get('length'); 
    }.property('@each.isLoaded')
```

I have changed .findQuery to .query but every time it is showing length as 0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just change `findQuery` to `query`.

After this a error message will appear in console:

```
Assertion failed: Not implemented: You must override the DS.FixtureAdapter::queryFixtures method to support querying the fixture store.
```

Like the message explain, just implement the `DS.FixtureAdapter#queryFixtures`.
The parameters passed to `queryFixtures` is: records, query, type. Where:

- `Records` is an array of plain javascript objects, that you will filter.
- `Query` is the object passed to `query` method of your ember data class.
- `Type` is the ember data class, where the query is call.

And the return is the filtered data.

For example, to perform a simple where like:

```
App.Person.query({ firstName: 'Tom' })
```

Just reopen your `DS.FixtureAdapter` with:

```
DS.FixtureAdapter.reopen({
    queryFixtures: function(records, query, type) {        
        return records.filter(function(record) {
            for(var key in query) {
                if (!query.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
                var value = query[key];
                if (record[key] !== value) { return false; }
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/GYbeT/) is a live demo.

Comment: I was about to post an answer but you augmented your answer very well so upvote for you :)

Comment: Thanks @intuitivepixel! Because ember-data lacks in some tutorials, sometimes I spend some time to provide additional info about the problem, when I have time :)

Comment: Thanks,@MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior It is working now But every time i am getting length as 0.

Comment: Aesthetically, and philosophically, what is the reasoning behind not having this by default in ember?

Comment: @ahnbizcad please see this thread for [more info](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1526).